# RealityKit: Incorrect Shadows with Directional Light

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, arkit, realitykit

I have a problem with shadows in `RealityKit` and `DirectionalLight`.

After doing some research from my [initial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77929614/realitykit-creating-sharp-shadows-with-lighting) question about this, I [downloaded an Xcode project](https://codingxr.com/articles/shadows-lights-in-realitykit/) that describes the basics of lights in `RealityKit`. It's simple enough.

One of the examples used in that sample project involved a `DirectionalLight`, which can be very helpful for lighting like the sun.

I took a look at the `DirectionalLight` option in the app, and added an extra sphere the scene:

[image: A screenshot of an Xcode iPhone 15 Pro with correct directional lighting.]

Here's the lighting for that:

```
private func addDirectionalLight() {
        let directionalLight = DirectionalLight()
        directionalLight.light.intensity = 100000
        directionalLight.shadow?.maximumDistance = 5
        directionalLight.shadow?.depthBias = 1
        directionalLight.look(at: [0, 0, 0], from: [-50, 20, 0], relativeTo: nil)
        
        addLight(directionalLight)
    }
```

I made the intensity of it pretty high so you can easily see the light (white part) vs the shadows (non-white part).

I then went to my own project.

I want to create a directional lighting setup to achieve an effect akin to the sun. I thought that would be easy... I would just have to look at how the sample project did it and make adjustments.

Well... I tried creating my own lighting setup as follows:

```
let directionalLight = DirectionalLight()
        directionalLight.light.intensity = 100000
        directionalLight.shadow?.maximumDistance = 3
        directionalLight.look(at: [0, 0, 0], from: [0, 100, 1200], relativeTo: nil)
        // directionalLight.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi/2, axis: [0, 1, 0])
        
        lightAnchor.addChild(directionalLight)
```

where `lightAnchor` is an `AnchorEntity` at [0, 0, 0] for the world.

Here's the result when applied to objects:

[image: A screenshot of an Xcode iPad Pro simulator with incorrect directional lighting.]

Do you notice anything? I circled it. It's like the lighting is being applied to each individual object without any sort of regard for the fact that another object is there.

In real life, a shadow would be casted from the sphere on top of the cube in addition to the shadow that is currently present. Look at the first image and pretend it is the top of the cube from the second photo. Yes, there's a shadow on the back of the sphere where the light doesn't hit, but ALSO on the plane it's on.

I am extremely confused.

The only thing I thought of is that the first image has a scale where the sphere in the center of the photo is about 3 meters wide... while my second image is at a much, much larger scale. That box is 150 meters wide.

But, that should not impact the lighting, right? I don't believe it should. Is my `DirectionalLight` in a bad position? I don't understand how it would be, considering that it hit box and sphere.

I simply want shadows like in the first image, but for some reason I cannot achieve that.

I really need some help on this. It would be amazing if someone could!

Also, happy Vision Pro day! :)

**EDIT 1/2:**

I changed to my actual model (which is just one, big USDZ — the first photos were just using example meshes) and lighting code to this:

```
let directionalLight = DirectionalLight()
        directionalLight.light.intensity = 10000
        directionalLight.shadow?.depthBias = 0.5
        directionalLight.shadow?.maximumDistance = 3
        directionalLight.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: -.pi/5, axis: [1, 0, 0])
        
        lightAnchor.addChild(directionalLight)
```

This results in shadows looking like this:

[image: A screenshot of an Xcode iPad Pro simulator with incorrect directional lighting.]

It looks kind of weird. I have tried looking at the documentation, but I still don't understand why I am not getting this right.

**EDIT 2/2:**

I have discovered another interesting property about shadows in relation to the `PerspectiveCamera`.

After thinking that the large dimensions of my model had an impact on the absence of shadows, I scaled down the model by a considerable amount.

This did actually partially solve the issue. I could now observe shadows on parts of my model:

[image: A screenshot of an Xcode iPad Pro simulator with shadows and a closer camera position.]

I then moved the `PerspectiveCamera` that I created back from the model a bit:

[image: A screenshot of an Xcode iPad Pro simulator with shadows and a more distant camera position.]

You have to look carefully here. Compare the two photos. I circled one particular part of the model where the change is very clear. The shadows moved, and even disappeared.

This also happens when I change the `fieldOfViewInDegrees` on the `PerspectiveCamera`.

This is very odd behavior. Why would the camera impact the shadows at all? Rendering settings? It's like I need to ignore the rendering settings and have them not change based on where the camera is/FOV/zoom level etc. Any solutions?

I really have no idea what to do and I'm worried. Especially since I want to animate the camera (or model) moving and zooming in/out. I also want to animate the position of the `DirectionalLight`.

Perhaps I need a more detailed explanation of `depthBias` and `maximumDistance` and how they relate to the `PerspectiveCamera`, its FOV and rendering.

Answer (score 1):

#### Shadows in iOS RealityKit

Use this code to setup shadows. The quality of shadows in RealityKit for iOS does not stand up to criticism. These shadows are difficult to compare to shadows in SceneKit, much less to shadows in 3D authoring tools such as Maya or Cinema4D. The edges of RK shadows are blurred, the shadows are semi-transparent. And unfortunately, RealityKit provides too few options for customizing shadows.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer().ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

[image]

```
struct ARViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {

    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let cube = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 1))
    let ball = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.3))
    let mat = SimpleMaterial(color: .gray, roughness: 1, isMetallic: false)
    
    init() {
        cube.model?.materials = [mat]
        ball.model?.materials = [mat]
    }        
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        arView.cameraMode = .nonAR
        ball.position.y = 0.55
        
        let sun = DirectionalLight()
        sun.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: -.pi/4, axis: [1, 1.2, 0])
        sun.light.intensity = 12_000
        sun.shadow = DirectionalLightComponent.Shadow()
        sun.shadow?.maximumDistance = 3
        sun.shadow?.depthBias = 0.5
                
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi/3, axis: [1, 0, 0])
        anchor.addChild(sun)
        anchor.addChild(cube)
        anchor.addChild(ball)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Update:

#### Testing USD model in Maya

I tested your USD model in Maya 2024 and I have to say that it works great with both types of shadows - `depth map` and `raytraced`. This is how the shadows react to the directional light's orientation.

[image]

#### Testing USD model in RealityKit for iOS

As I said earlier, shadows in RealityKit for iOS are not as sharp  (and not opaque) as in authoring software. Here is what RealityKit shadows look like (not what you expect):

[image]

```
struct ARViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let seaShore = try! Entity.load(named: "CoastRanges.usd")
    let sun = DirectionalLight()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        arView.cameraMode = .nonAR
        
        sun.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: -.pi/9, axis: [1, 0, 0])
        sun.light.intensity = 5_000
        sun.shadow = .init()
        sun.shadow?.maximumDistance = 5.5    // default 5
        sun.shadow?.depthBias = 0.75         // default 1
       
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi/6, axis: [0.8,-1.3, 0])
        anchor.position = [4, 2,-11]
        anchor.addChild(sun)
        anchor.addChild(seaShore)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It looks like the difference is the anchor? You have one anchor. I have to add the light to the same anchor as the model in order to make this work?

Comment: It is also important to consider that the position of the directional light does not matter, only the orientation matters.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. I just don’t understand what I was doing wrong. The anchors?

Comment: Use `orientation` property instead of `.look(at:from:)` method. Also, reduce light's intensity and make sure that light's rays are not perpendicular to the top side of a cube.

Comment: Hello, I edited my original question (look at "EDIT"). I used `orientation` instead of `.look(at: from:)` and also made sure that the rays were not perpendicular to the top of the model. I changed from the model in my original post to my actual model. I don't think the anchor should have any impact on this. I don't understand why a simple thing is causing problems.

Comment: Also, remember that my original post highlighted that my actual model is pretty large in dimensions (I have reasons for this). I know your model is using normal sizes. But there shouldn't be an impact from that...

Comment: Update: I tried scaling it down by a considerable amount (99%) and it still isn't working. I've tried everything. :(

Comment: Update: I apologize for all the comments. The camera seems to be impacting how the shadows behave. I updated the original post under the second "Edit".

Comment: @Joe, Editing a question after it has been answered is very bad practice, as it invalidates the answer.

Comment: I apologize! The primary issue is the same, even after the adjustments. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Share your model via file sharing service, please.

Comment: I think I might be good just by messing around with these values to be honest, but if you really want to play with it, here you go. It's a very complicated problem because I have a camera that needs to zoom in and out (either FOV or position change)... of course I need the shadows to not change when that happens. It won't be a very large zoom, only a slight one. (https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0aemxZVP2Zc2U4g06_kFjtwFw#CoastRanges)

Comment: Thank you. I was just looking at my model and I think I might have also found a formula to make the shadows work really well.

Comment: You can use [fake shadows](https://medium.com/geekculture/realitykit-911-fake-shadows-for-stationary-models-78387aabf42c) that are part of a texture.

Comment: Thanks. I now animated the camera moving in and just found out that the shadows are flickering. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: In theory, there should be a way, as viewing objects in AR doesn't result in this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

From your explanations and observations of how the shadow behaves with large meshes and movement of PerspectiveCamera, I believe your issue is with the ‘maximumDistance’ property of [DirectionalLight.Shadow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/directionallightcomponent/shadow).

This property tells RealityKit how far from the viewpoint (PerspectiveCamera) it will consider meshes for shadow-casting calculations. So in your case with very large meshes and maximumDistance = 3, the camera is simply too far away from the object for RealityKit to even consider calculating its casted shadow. This would also happen  when you move the camera too far away from your USDZ model as in your second example.

Try playing with the maximumDistance property to find a value that better captures the use-case and scale of your RealityKit scene. For example:

```
var directional = DirectionalLight()
directional.shadow = .init(maximumDistance: 128, depthBias: 1.0)
```

Keep in mind that the ‘sharpness’ and quality of cast shadows decrease as the maximum distance is increased, so I suggest finding a value as close to the estimated maximum distance for your use case as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am trying to create a view that has a fairly low FOV and higher distance from the model, which makes it have a more isometric look. Does this mean that when I move the camera in and out in position, the shadows will change? It looks like it. I guess I will have to create a mechanism to counteract that?

Comment: Also, wouldn't the values of `maximumDistance` increase the quality as you increase its value? As it's the distance from the camera the camera will render shadows? It seems like the opposite happens. The camera doesn't render them as well when the value is higher.

Comment: I'm also confused because the `depthBias` interferes with this too. It doesn't just seem to be the `maximumDistance`. I'm just confused because I cannot have an understanding of how all of these things combine and impact the shadows. At this moment, I feel like I am guessing combinations to find shadows that kind of work. But, I need to understand it in order to truly get an optimized look.

Comment: As long as the distance between your camera and model of interest is within the maximum shadow distance you set on the directional light, it should render shadows properly even when you move your camera. 

You could update the maximum distance dynamically, making sure it is always more than whatever distance your camera is from a certain model/position.

Comment: I’m guessing the reduced quality of the shadows makes sense from a computational point of view, as a greater maximum distance means RealityKit has to consider and calculate shadows for (potentially) more models and at longer distances.

Comment: This is likely correct. I guess I can make my model very small to counteract this? That makes sense to me.

Comment: In my experience, messing with depthBias mostly shifts the shadow layer in weird ways. I would leave it at 1.0, at least until you find a proper distance value that works and then see how depthBias affects the outcome. To quickly test and fine-tune these parameters in your scene, I suggest adding simple UI controls to change their value at runtime. I did so by binding a computed property for each value to SwiftUI controls, where the values are set directly to the directional light in the setter

Comment: Thanks for the info. It just feels like I'm guessing though. Like it's almost impossible to get the correct combination to get pretty sharp shadows at from a longer distance away. The first photo in this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77929614/realitykit-creating-sharp-shadows-with-lighting) shows what I'm trying to do. Is there any other way to fine tune my shadows? Creating a shadow component? I even tried looking at Metal. I want to keep things simple, so I don't know about that.

Comment: Hmm... I guess making the model really small might work.